# Unable to access HTTPS service using Spring Rest Template - TrustStore issue?

Tags: spring, ssl, https, resttemplate, truststore

While accessing a HTTPS service I am facing the below issue :

**Error:**
`..Certification authentication failed</TITLE>
...
An attempt to authenticate with a client certificate failed.
A valid client certificate is required to make this connection.`

I am using Spring RestTemplate excahnge API :

`restTemplate.exchange(reqInfo.getUrl(),HttpMethod.GET,requestEntity,String.class);`

I tried 2 methods to provide the trustStore but still the error persists:

1.) Passing as arguments :
`java -cp -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="trustStore.jks" 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="pwd"  Test`

2.) Setting the property

`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","path to truststore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","pwd");`

Also I tried with  simple Java code using HTTPclient then it works fine but with SPring RestTemplate none of option is working , am i missing something here ?

Note :  If I do curl of that URL I get the same error as truststore is not provided . Hence I am assuming that this issue is due to TrustStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the above issue .

While building the SSL context I did not load the key store ( although I was passing it via arguments) due to which I was getting **Certification authentication failed** as the Key store was not available .

Below code fixed the issue : (added **loadKeyMaterial** )

```
sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                            .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePwd).build();
```